# RxJS - Why would I want to use throwError and not simply throw an error?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, rxjs, observable

First of all, I want to make it clear that I know the difference between Rx throwError operator and JS's throw keyword. I just wanted to know why would I use the throwError operator? What am I gaining by creating a new observable that all it does is to throw an error the second anyone subscribes to it?

Long story short, why would I want to do this:

```
.catchError(err => throw "error!!")
```

Over this:

```
.catchError(err => throwError("error!!"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing to be gained in using `throwError` in that particular situation. I prefer using `throw`. You'd use `throwError` - which is an observable creator, not an operator - in situations in which you want to declare an observable that emits only an error notification, rather than imperatively throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

If you just throw an error, it will end the pipeline. If you use `throwError`, it will return a new observable that is going to emit that error, essentially will pass it on down the pipeline. `throwError(error)` is equivalent to this:

```
return new Observable(observer=>{
      observer.error(error)
    })
```

Comment: don't really understand your explanation since `throwError` emits an error, all the operators declared in your pipeline will be skipped (except `catchError` or `retry`), so I don't see any difference with native `throw`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the syntax is the only difference. There is no reason to use *throw* instead of *throwError* or the other way around. Choose one approach with your team and stick to it.

**Proof**

```js
// Error using reactive throwError
// logs error 'oops!!'
of(1)
    .pipe(
        switchMap(
           (x) => throwError('oops!!'))
        )
    .subscribe({
        next: console.log,  // not called
        error: console.error, 
        complete: () => console.log('complete!'),  // not called
    }); 

// Error using imperative throw
// logs error 'oops!!'
of(1)
    .pipe(
        switchMap((x) => {
            throw 'oops!!';
        })
    )
    .subscribe({
        next: console.log,  // not called
        error: console.error,
        complete: () => console.log('complete!'), // not called
    });
```

The output is the same in both ways. Note the completion handler which is not called in both scenarios, according to the [Observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html).

Answer (score 0):

May be problematic to use throwError inside pipe operator as throwError observable may be just passed down the pipe depending on subsequent operations. See this article for details: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/throwerror-is-not-throw-error-ad6c76c53377